# Node.js/Express, Expecting callback function, found a Object undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, mongoose

I am trying to use app.get, but it keeps throwing an error, Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined].
The line of code is

```
app.get('/', routes.show);
```

The route routes to a method called show, which is located in my routes.js file.

```
var Test = require('./../public/javascripts/db');

exports.show = function(req, res){
   Test.find(function(err, tests) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('index', {title: 'Test Bank', tests: tests});
        }
    });
};
```

Test is reference to my database file written using mongoose.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly requiring routes.js in your app.js? That would leave routes undefined.